# Return a parameter of an object

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I would like to make a function to return me the name of a person when I give an id to my function. Here's what I've done :

```
nameOfPerson(personjson, personId){
  let id = personId;
  let json = personjson.json();
  let data = [];

  //console.log("id in nameOfPerson method " + id);
  //console.log("json in nameOfPerson method  " + JSON.stringify(json))

  for (let person of json){
      let newPerson = new Person()
      newPerson.text = person.firstName + ' ' + person.lastName,
      newPerson.id  =  person.id
      if (id == newPerson.id){
        data.push(newPerson.text)
      }
      console.log("data on nameOfPerson method " + JSON.stringify(data))
      return JSON.stringify(data);
  }
}
```

which is called by this function :

```
getPersonNamebyId(personId): Promise<Person[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.PersonsUrl)
                      .toPromise()
                      .then(response => this.nameOfPerson(response, personId))
                      .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

and this one is called here :

```
//parsingFunction
  parseAppointment(appointmentJson) {
    let data = new Array();
    let json = appointmentJson.json()
      for (let appointment of json) {
        let newAppointment = new Appointment()
        newAppointment.text = appointment.reason +' '+ this.personsService.getPersonNamebyId(appointment.personId), // this.personsService.getPersonNamebyId(appointment.personId)
        newAppointment.id = appointment.id,
        newAppointment.ownerId  =  appointment.personId,
        newAppointment.startDate  =  appointment.date,
        newAppointment.endDate  =  this.add30mnTo(appointment.date),
        data.push(newAppointment);
      }
      console.log(data)
      return data
    }
```

and called here :

```
  getAppointments(): Promise<Appointment[]> {

    return this.http.get(this.AppointmentUrlGet)
                 .toPromise()
                 .then(response => this.parseAppointment(response))
                 .catch(this.handleError);

  }
```

the objective of the whole thing is to convert an object of this :

```
[
{
id: "bc127c74-377b-4ea6-925a-3dd5e0227482",
reason: "testing",
date: "2017-06-22T14:59:55.000Z",
personId: "8090210d-e154-4db0-96c1-42688f45971a"
},
{
id: "bc127c74-377b-4ea6-925a-3dd5e0227482",
reason: "testing02",
date: "2017-06-22T14:59:55.000Z",
personId: "8090210d-e154-4db0-96c1-42688f45971a"
}
]
```

of an object of person ( id = appointment.id , text = reason + ownerName) that's why i use the owner/person.id on my getPersonById function.

i would like to get the person name attached to the personId

on my console log, it says [object object] not the name of the person...
( also the same thing on the appointment's cell)

Could you tell me where my mistake is?

thanks very much

Comment: just do console.log(data), then it won't give object object

Comment: Inside `nameOfPerson` method, you return on first object of the array. Could there be a mistake there? You seem to never go through the whole array. And can you post how you call `getPersonNamebyId` method and where do you expect to see the name of the person?

Comment: edited thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i can see, you actually just want to do this:

```
var nameOfPerson = (personjson, personId) => {
  var {firstName,lastName,id} = 
    personjson.json().find(el=>el.id === personId);

  return firstName && lastName&&id
    ?  { text: firstName+lastName, id } //maybe Object.assign(new Person(),{text: ... }) instead
    :  { id: "unknown"};
};
```

Use it like this:

```
var {text, id} = nameOfPerson(json,12);
console.log(" text",text,"id",id);
```

Or in a promise:

```
 getjson().then(
  json => nameOfPerson(json,12)
 )
 .then(
   ({text, id}) => console.log(text,id)
);
```

Comment: looks like they wanted `id` too

Comment: thanks for you answer but i didn't understand your answer, could you please explain ? why did you use var {firstname,lastName,id} ? i already parsed it on an other function. i would like to check on the parsed array if my personId ( parameter of my function ) is equal to the personId on the array and return the personName attached.

Comment: @mehdy driouech thats what the *.find* does. The new person just contains firstName,lastName and id, thats why i *destructured* the json object.